# Upgrade to PostGIS 3.0 in pgAdmin

Tags: postgis, pgadmin-4, upgrade

I would like to use the new ST_TileEnvelope() function from PostGIS 3.0. My current version is 2.4.4.

I would like to update to PostGIS 3.0 in pgAdmin. Is this possible?

I have tried 
`ALTER EXTENSION postgis UPDATE TO '3.0.0';`

This returns the error...

```
ERROR:  extension "postgis" has no update path from version "2.4.4" to version "3.0.0"
```

I am on Windows 10.

I initially installed our older version of postGIS (2.4.4) with no postGIS file on my computer. Nevertheless, I downloaded postgis-3.0.0 and I can now find this folder in the Windows File Explorer. 
[image]

Comment: http://postgis.net/2019/10/20/postgis-3.0.0/

Comment: Before executing any SQL command, you need the package on your computer and you didn't tell us your OS. The SQL command you mentioned is just picking what is available on your file system.

Comment: @etrimaille Okay, I updated the question with these details.

Comment: In your file browser, we can read that your folder is called `postgis-3.0.0alpha1`. You don't want a alpha version, and as you can notice, the `Date modified is from 26 May 2019` in your file browser, which match with https://postgis.net/2019/05/26/postgis-3.0.0alpha1/. PLease be sure to download the Postgis 3.0.0. Then you should follow the Windows way to install postgis.

Comment: @etrimaille  We are using Amazon RDS, so it would not be helpful to have the package on my computer. How do you go about installing PostGIS through RDS? It appears the most up to date postGIS version is not available.

Comment: @GNG now that's one hell of a piece of missing information...as you seem to have found out, Amazon RDS has a range of supported versions and will likely not include a new major version before the first few minor version updates. *pgAdmin* is nothing more than a client, don't confuse it with anything DB server related.

Comment: Ohh, ok, you clearly didn't tell us everything. When I asked you your OS, I was talking about the OS where PostGIS is installed. As @Th

Comment: Ohh, ok, you clearly didn't tell us everything. When I asked you about your OS, I was talking about the OS where PostGIS is installed. As @ThingumaBob mentioned, pgAdmin is only a client, connected to a server. Amazon RDS is definitely different than saying that you are on Windows, you should edit your question. I think you should read more about what client/server architecture. Your PostGIS version is controlled by Amazon RDS I supposed.